# Is this a vaild variable name?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

For those that have experience in PowerShell, is this considered to be a valid variable name?

Code:

```
$[?@+-stuff] is a valid variable name in PowerShell.
```

Answer (score 4):

- It's a valid? Yes, if you wrap it inside curly brackets. This is required because of the special characters.

`${[?@+-stuff]} = "foo"`

- Is it a good name? No. You should keep it simple..

If you made an effort to research it you would have figured it out yourself.
Check of the help documentation the @mjolinor suggested. Especially the part called:

> VARIABLE NAMES THAT INCLUDE SPECIAL CHARACTERS

We're all here to help each other, so please show us some respect and behave like a grown-up.